# ATmega8 up/down counter not counting correctly

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I'm wanting to build a 5 digit up/down counter.  When I can get the simulation to work I'll be much happier buying the bits and pieces to build it.  What I have so far uses the ATmega8, but quite frankly any solution would work for me as long as the components are reasonably cheap.

I found a simple up counter on the web and have changed it to include a down function also.  I removed some hideous `_delay_ms(1000)` statements from the code which were probably there to prevent multiple counts while the input is being held?  It made the counter very slow and unresponsive.  Here's what I have so far:
[image: Circuit diagram]

The problem I have is that it doesn't count up and when it counts down it doesn't display zero.

The code:
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
#define F_CPU 4000000

volatile uint16_t digits[5]={0,0,0,0,0}; //INITIALISE VARIABLE TO STORE INDIVIDUAL DIGITS OF THE NUMBER

void breakup(uint16_t num) {  //FUNCTION TO FIND THE INDIVIDUAL DIGITS OF THE NUMBER
                              // AND STORE THEM IN A GLOBAL VARIABLE
    DDRD=0xFF; // INITIALISE PORTD AS ALL OUTPUT
    PORTD=0x00;
    unsigned int i=0;
    while (num!=0) {
        digits[i]=num%10;
        num=num/10;
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        PORTD=(1<<i); // 'i'th PORTD GIVEN HIGH
        display(digits[i]);
        _delay_us(600);
        PORTD=(0<<i); //'i'th PORTD GIVEN LOW
    }
}

void display (uint16_t num) { // Bit patterns changed from the original to correct for my hardware layout.
    DDRB=0b11111111;
    PORTB=0xFF;
    switch(num) {
        case 0:
        PORTB=0b00111111;
        break;
        case 1:
        PORTB=0b00000110;
        break;
        case 2:
        PORTB=0b01011011;
        break;
        case 3:
        PORTB=0b01001111;
        break;
        case 4:
        PORTB=0b01100110;
        break;
        case 5:
        PORTB=0b01101101;
        break;
        case 6:
        PORTB=0b01111101;
        break;
        case 7:
        PORTB=0b00000111;
        break;
        case 8:
        PORTB=0b01111111;
        break;
        case 9:
        PORTB=0b01101111;
        break;
        default:
        PORTB=0xFF;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    DDRB=0xFF; //Initialise PORTB as all outputs.
    DDRC=0x00;   //Initialise PORTC as all inputs.
    PORTC=0b01000000;  //Enable internal pullup for the reset pin.
    char x;
    char down_button_press = 0;
    char up_button_press = 0;
    uint16_t i, c=5;
    while(1) {
        x=PINC&0b00000001; //Check condition of PC0 DOWN button.
        if (x==0 && down_button_press==0) {
            c--;
            breakup(c); //Pass c to the breakup routine and display.
            down_button_press++;
        }
        if (x==1) {
        down_button_press = 0;
        }
        x=PINC&0b00000010; //Check condition of PC1 UP button.
        if (x==0 && up_button_press==0) {
            c++;
            breakup(c); //Pass c to the breakup routine and display.
            up_button_press++;
        }
        if (x==1) {
        up_button_press = 0;
        }
        else
        breakup(c);
    }
}
```

The counting up and counting down bits of the code at the end are essentially identical, so I don't know why it counts down, but not up.  In an attempt to stop the counter making multiple counts while the button is pressed I have included a sort of latch `&& up_button_press==0`.  It's not supposed to be debouncing code, it's just so I get single increments and single decrements with each button press.
What I have managed to work out is that is doesn't count up because the up-latch isn't clearing when the button goes back high - so the `&& up_button_press==0` condition is never true:

```
if (x==1) {
    up_button_press = 0;
    }
```

If someone can help me to get the thing to work I'd appreciate it.  I can add the Proteus simulation file if that helps?

Comment: Sorry, but the story and the pictures are not relevant, but makes your question less clear. I suggest deleting it. (sidenote: Not sure what Solid State Discs will be good for her, but anyway). SO is not a consulting or coding service. See [ask]. (and using spaces in expressions greatly enhaces readability).

Comment: SSD = Seven Segment Display in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are, as you know a couple problems with the code.

1) regarding the code block, in `breakup()` that starts with:

```
while (num!=0) {
```

This loop should always iterate 5 times, regardless of the value of `num`

This will result in all possible digits being displayed, including 0

The following code is how I would implement the desired functionality.

Notice the conversion of most magic numbers to have a meaningful names.

Notice the cleanup of the logic in the `main()` function.

Notice the extension for the possible displayed values from 16k to 99999.

Notice the removal of the clutter and unneeded variables.

Notice the use of meaningful (and unique) variable names.

I'm wondering why setting the 7 segment digits using the internal pullup resistors rather than the `PINxy` outputs.  But I left it the same as the OPs posted code.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define F_CPU 4000000

#define NUM_DIGITS (5)
#define MAX_DISPLAYED_VALUE (99999)

#define UP_BUTTON (0b00000010)
#define DN_BUTTON (0b00000001)

#define DIGIT_0   (0b00111111)
#define DIGIT_1   (0b00000110)
#define DIGIT_2   (0b01011011)
#define DIGIT_3   (0b01001111)
#define DIGIT_4   (0b01100110)
#define DIGIT_5   (0b01101101)
#define DIGIT_6   (0b01111101)
#define DIGIT_7   (0b00000111)
#define DIGIT_8   (0b01111111)
#define DIGIT_9   (0b01101111)

// prototypes
void initialize( void );
void display   ( uint8_t digitValue );
void breakup   ( uint32_t num );

uint8_t digits[]={0,0,0,0,0}; //INITIALISE VARIABLE TO STORE INDIVIDUAL DIGITS OF THE NUMBER



int main(void)
{

    uint32_t  num = 0;  // initialize value to display

    initialize();       // initialize hardware

    while(1)
    {
        if (PINC & DN_BUTTON)
        { // then down button pressed
            if( num > 0 )
            {
                num--;
            }
        }

        else if ( PINC & UP_BUTTON)
        { // then up button pressed
            if( num < MAX_DISPLAYED_VALUE )
            {
                num++;
            }
        } // end if which button
        breakup( num );
    } // end while forever
} // end function: main



void breakup(uint32_t num)
{  //FUNCTION TO FIND THE INDIVIDUAL DIGITS OF THE NUMBER
                              // AND STORE THEM IN A GLOBAL VARIABLE
    for( size_t i=0; i< NUM_DIGITS; i++)
    {
        digits[i]= (uint8_t)(num%10);
        num=num/10;
    }

    for( size_t i=0; i<NUM_DIGITS; i++)
    {
        display(digits[i]); // preset the value to display
        PORTD=(1<<i);  // select which 7 segment digit
        _delay_us(600);
        PORTD = 0;    // unselect all the seven segment displays
    }
}



void display ( uint8_t digitValue)
{ // Bit patterns changed from the original to correct for my hardware layout.

    switch(digitValue)
    {
        case 0:
            PORTB=DIGIT_0;
            break;

        case 1:
            PORTB=DIGIT_1;
            break;

        case 2:
            PORTB=DIGIT_2;
            break;

        case 3:
            PORTB=DIGIT_3;
            break;

        case 4:
            PORTB=DIGIT_4;
            break;

        case 5:
            PORTB=DIGIT_5;
            break;

        case 6:
            PORTB=DIGIT_6;
            break;

        case 7:
            PORTB=DIGIT_7;
            break;

        case 8:
            PORTB=DIGIT_8;
            break;

        case 9:
            PORTB=DIGIT_9;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } // end switch
} // end function: display



void initialize()
{
    DDRB=0xFF;          // all outputs
    //PORTB=0xFF;       // enable all internal pullups

    DDRC=0x00;         // all inputs.
    PORTC=0b01000000;  //Enable internal pullup for the reset pin.

    DDRD=0xFF;         // all outputs
    PORTD=0x00;        // disable all internal pullups
} // end function: initialize
```

Comment: This is very much appreciated, but I get 16 errors during the build with this code.  I don't know anything like enough C to understand why.  Can you spot the reason why it's not displaying 00000?

Comment: please post, here as a comment, one of those errors.

Comment: the first couple of lines in my answer state the problem of why 0 is not displayed.   Specifically, the processing loop is never entered if the value is 0

Comment: ../ALL_NEW_ATMEGA8_COUNTER.c:24: error: expected ')' before 'digitValue'
../ALL_NEW_ATMEGA8_COUNTER.c:25: error: expected ')' before 'num'
../ALL_NEW_ATMEGA8_COUNTER.c:27: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'digits'
../ALL_NEW_ATMEGA8_COUNTER.c: In function 'main':
../ALL_NEW_ATMEGA8_COUNTER.c:34: error: 'uint32_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
../ALL_NEW_ATMEGA8_COUNTER.c:34: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../ALL_NEW_ATMEGA8_COUNTER.c:34: error: for each function it appears in.)
...

Comment: To start, it looks like you removed the #include <stdint.h> statement that you (and I) did not post in your question.  That statement brings in the definitions for `uint32_t`  `uint8_t` and your original `uint16_t`  You also need to include the header that defines all the port names, etc so things like `PORTB` are defined

Comment: Thanks.  No errors now, but now the display flickers and mostly shows 88888.

Comment: that 88888 is probably all the segments being turned ON.  I'm not totally familar with the 7 segment displays, but I thought that setting the data bits to 0 turned the led segments off.   In any case I'm modifying the function `breakup()`  to help avoid that flickering by presetting the data outputs before enabling any 7segment display.

Comment: question: when the 7 segment displays are not selected, is the last data value latched?   If so, then the `main()`  loop could be modified to only call `breakup()` when the value to display has changed.  This would also help with reducing any flicker.

Comment: +1 for addressing the other problems as well. Some minor details: _from 16k to 99999_ -> you probably mean _from 64k_. `DIGIT_0` to `DIGIT_9` could be put in a byte array, and the `switch` could then be eliminated (with a check on 'overflow').

Comment: @Danny_ds, I agree with the putting the digit bit patterns in an array, but I did not want to change the code to the point were the OP would not recognize it.  Your right, about 64k to 99999 rather than 16k to 99999.   Sometimes I get in too much of a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here:

```
x=PINC&0b00000010; //Check condition of PC1 UP button.
...
if (x==1) {
    up_button_press = 0;
```

x will be `2` if the button is pressed (since your mask is `0x2` for checking the second bit of PORTC), so check:

```
if (x==2) {
    up_button_press = 0;
```

Comment: That does change things, but now the up button has to remain depressed for the number to be displayed.  It's given me something to play with anyway.  Let me spend a bit of time seeing what I can do with it.  Thanks.

Comment: @PeteG - That's because you're using `else breakup(c);` at the bottom of your while loop.

Comment: Brilliant!! I'd just worked that out and now it's working.  Thanks @Ctx

Comment: @PeteG - You also might want to check the limits of `c` before counting up/down (`c == 0` or `c == 0xffff`). Check what happens if `c == 0` and you press _Down_.

Comment: Yes, I've added those in it counts down to 1 and won't display a 0.  I think that c does actually equal zero, but it's not displaying it - it just stays at 1.  I can start it with `uint16_t i, c=0;` and that displays zero ok, but it won't decrement to zero on the display.?